# What is the best way to Parse a scanned PDF file using PHP or JS?

Tags: parsing, pdf, ocr

I have a translation website and I would like to parse PDF files so that I can count words and I set the price for translation.

I have tried Poppler JS before. But It can't handle the scanned files. How should I handle them?

For example this PDF is a scanned article. It is a PDF file but each page is a picture and I need to extract the text:

[image]

Comment: What are you wanting to parse? Are the pdfs image based scans or document based (searchable)? Do you have any samples?

Comment: For example, this one https://prnt.sc/w26nbw. It is a scanned article. It is a pdf file but it's each page is a picture actually and I cant extract the text...

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. What you want is a way to extract the text from an Image. This is called Optical Character Recognition also known as OCR. I will edit your question and then provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an OCR library. There are a bunch of options to do this, here are some Software Recommendation Stack Exchange links:

[Scan Text Document To PDF With OCR](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36598/scan-text-document-to-pdf-with-ocr)

[JavaScript library for OCR](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33785/javascript-library-for-ocr)